# Oracle Constraint Inquiries

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I have an Oracle Database and I have a couple tables which I will attempt to illustrate as best as my creative mind can:

> > **COMPANIES**
>
> {PK = COMPANY_ID}
>
> > **SUPPLIERS**
>
> {PK = SUPPLIER_ID}
>
> > **COMPANY_SUPPLIERS**
>
> {PK = SUPPLIER_ID, COMPANY_ID}
>
> {FK = COMPANIES.COMPANY_ID} {FK = SUPPLIERS.SUPPLIER_ID}
>
> > **COMPANY_USERS**
>
> {PK = COMPANY_USERS_ID}
>
> {FK = COMPANIES.COMPANY_ID}
>
> > **COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS**
>
> {PK = COMPANY_USER_USER, COMPANY_SUPPLIER_ID}
>
> {FK = COMPANY_USERS.COMPANY_USERS_ID}{FK = SUPPLIERS.SUPPLIER_ID}

Where PK = primary Key and FK = a foreign key to one of the 5 tables.

Let us say that we have rule where

```
select count(*) 
   from COMPANIES C, 
        SUPPLIERS S, 
        COMPANY_SUPPLIERS CS, 
        COMPANY_USERS CU, 
        COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS CUS
where 
   COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS.COMPANY_USERS_ID = COMPANY_USERS.COMPANY_USERS_ID
and
   COMPANY_USERS.COMPANY_ID = COMPANIES.COMPANY_ID
and
   COMPANIES.COMPANY_ID = COMPANY_SUPPLIERS.COMPANY_ID
and
   SUPPLIERS .SUPPLIER_ID = COMPANY_SUPPLIERS.SUPPLIER_ID
and 
   COMPANY_SUPPLIERS.SUPPLIER_ID = COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS.SUPPLIER_ID
```

should give the same result

```
   select count(*) from COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS;
```

Is it possible to enforce this with constraints and if yes, how do I do so? Is the database designed poorly? Should I just enforce this via triggers?

Comment: Dont use A,B,C,D as table aliases. Its impossible to read. The order of the expressions in the where clause should make sense (although it doesnt matter for the database).

Comment: What's the difference between COMPANY_SUPPLIERS AND COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS? Is it possible that COMPANY_SUPPLIERS can be computed from the other tables?

Comment: @wolφi company suppliers represents the relationship between a company and a supplier; however, the company user suppliers represents the relationship between a user from a company with a supplier. Some company users may not be allowed interact with all suppliers.

Comment: So company_suppliers is a subset of company_user_suppliers? Or are there attributes in c.u.s. that are not in c.s.?

Comment: @wolφi There are attributes in CUS that are not in CS. I just didn't show them here because I didn't feel they were relevant to the constraints. Perhaps I made a mistake in not doing so.

Comment: No, that's absolutely fine. Simplifying the examples helps a lot. Sorry, I asked the wrong question: Are there attributes in CS that are not in CUS?

Comment: @wolφi Yea. For example, the address and accounting information of the supplier may be kept in the CS but the contact for the sales representative or the last date of contact for each CU may be different (CUS).

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the user in COMPANY_USER_SUPPLIERS is from a company that is related to that supplier in COMPANY_SUPPLIERS.